# Highcharts (Highstock) "inputEditDateFormat" doesn't work

Tags: highcharts

I need to set my rangeSelectors Date to this format dd/mm/yy.

The inputDateFormat works well, but you can see when you click to edit the date it changes from dd/mm/yy  to  mm/dd/yy. (from 27/09/21 to 09/27/21)

Somebody could help me with it please ?

Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/igrasso/fyrj8n5d/1/

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json', function (data) {
// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


    rangeSelector: {
            inputDateFormat: '%d/%m/%y',
            inputEditDateFormat: '%d/%m/%y',
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: Hi @Binho, It seems to work well in my case. The first date is `27.09.2021` with and without editing.

Comment: @ppotaczek thanks for answering. It is not working on my end as you can see in the link below. The date should be 27/09/2021. - https://ibb.co/SQYwD7S

Comment: Thanks for the video. The difference results from the fact that the text format is based on the default format used in a specific country. Please check this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15936 and add a comment there if you want.